# .net Framework csproj regenerates after file deletion

Tags: c#, git, visual-studio, csproj, .net-4.8

I'm trying to change my .NET framework project to include all the files with the following rule:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="**\*.cs"/>
    <Compile Remove="bin\**\*;obj\**\*"/>
</ItemGroup>
```

Every time I add a file to the project it's building properly (and does not modify the `.csproj`) while including all of the files in the build, but when I delete a file from the project it's regenerates the `.csproj` file to include each file separately and deletes this line :

```
<Compile Include="**\*.cs"/>
```

How can I make sure my `.csproj` stays the same even when I delete a file from the project?

I expect the `.csproj` file to stay the same in order to prevent git conflicts when merging branches that were developed in parallel.

**EDIT**: I couldn't share the whole project so I replicated the problem on a new one.

This is the `.csproj` file - https://github.com/gavrielor/CSProjTest/blob/main/CSProjTestClassLibrary/CSProjTestClassLibrary.csproj

And this is the whole project: https://github.com/gavrielor/CSProjTest/tree/main

If you delete one of the class files in the `CSProjTestClassLibrary` and than build/rebuild the `.csproj` file will replicate the bug I mentioned above.

Comment: Are you using an SDK-style csproj or a Classic-style csproj?

Comment: @Dai I'm using classic-style csproj

Comment: How did you delete a file? Can you show the csproj?

Comment: @shingo I deleted the file directly from the solution explorer in VS. I added the source file to the main post

Comment: "but when I delete a file from the project". Technically, you "delete" the file from the file system, and you "remove" the file from the project. If you only remove it from the project, the only way the project can know this is to list every file you want to include. Maybe if you do both at the same time it's doing it out of order. Perhaps if you only delete the file from the file system it will automatically disappear from the project. Though, it wouldn't surprise me if you have to unload and reload the project for it to be reflected. (Just guessing.)

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't need the second line, since neither the `bin` nor the `obj` folder contain .cs files. I'm assuming that complex term confuses Visual Studio somehow.

And then (at least if you use SDK style project files) you can just remove the whole block, since including all .cs files recursively is the default, unless default inclusions are explicitly disabled in the `<PropertyGroup>` section.

Comment: I tried both of the solutions, and neither helped. after creating a class rebuilding deleting a class and rebuilding again the csproj includes all of the files seperatly.

Comment: Weird, can you edit your question and include the whole .csproj file? I'm assuming some other part plays a role here.

Comment: I added the source file to the main post

Comment: @MaorArnon Then I strongly recommend to first upgrade the project to SDK style. The old format doesn't really support wildcard includes (or at least it was never used that way), therefore VS doesn't use it.